# What is the best way to encrypt a password symmetrically with spring

Tags: spring-security, encryption-symmetric

I am developing a spring-mvc application running on a linux server and I have to store user passwords in the MySQL database and I need these passwords to be accessible to the users in clear text if needed.

As I am not going to store passwords in clear text and I cannot used hash encoders, what is the most secure way say using spring-security to store passwords

- which symmetric encryption to use?
- What is the best strategy to store the key?

Comment: Why do you need to have the password in clear text. It seems a huge security hole! Then don't use any encryption. It is the same...

Comment: User requirement, i know all about security hole, they just want it this way. I need it in clear text only when user forgets its password (i know of a typical restore password functionality)

Comment: Then implement your own encoder with org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder. I think it's the easy way. You will have full control on decryption when needed.